# How to get matching and non matching rows from a SQL Join

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, join

I have two table joined and I want a result that shows all matching and non matching rows. Is it possible in SQL?

These are the tables and the query...

```sql
 CREATE TABLE #Day (id int, EID int, PID varchar(10), [Day] int, Shift varchar(10))
 CREATE TABLE #Night (id int, EID int, PID varchar(10), [Day] int, Shift varchar(10))

 INSERT INTO #Day 
 SELECT Atten_ID, EID, PID, DATEPART(DD,in_time) AS [Day], shift
   FROM Attendance
  WHERE (shift = 'D')

 INSERT INTO #Night 
 SELECT Atten_ID, EID, PID, DATEPART(DD,in_time) AS [Day], shift
   FROM Attendance
  WHERE (shift = 'N')

 SELECT #Day.EID, #Day.PID, #Day.Day, #Day.Shift AS DShift, #Night.Shift AS NShift 
   FROM #Day
        JOIN #Night ON #Day.EID = #Night.EID
                   AND #Day.PID = #Night.PID
                   AND #Day.Day = #Night.Day
```

Result should be like this...

```
EID |  PID  | Day | DShift   | NShift
______________________________________
100 |  S001 |  01 |  D       |   N
100 |  S001 |  02 |  D       |   -
100 |  S001 |  03 |  -       |   N
```

Comment: You mean like [FULL OUTER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use FULL OUTER JOIN

```
 SELECT COALESCE(d.EID,n.EID),
        COALESCE(d.PID,n.PID),
        COALESCE(d.Day,n.Day),
        d.Shift AS DShift,
        n.Shift AS NShift 
   FROM #Day d
        FULL JOIN #Night n ON d.EID = n.EID AND d.PID = n.PID AND d.Day = n.Day
```

Comment: Thanks, But an error said: multi-part identifier "#Day.Shift" could not be bound. What is this problem?

Comment: @Deva: The table name is aliased, use `d.Shift` instead of `#Day.Shift`

Answer (score 1):

Just a few notes in addition to Sheen's answer:

A `left join` would show all rows from the left table, and matching rows from the right table.

A `full join` would show all rows from both tables.

See [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

In reply to your comment, you could use a `case`.  That allows you to return different values under different conditions:

```
select  ...
,       case 
        when d.Shift is not null and n.Shift is not null then 'D/N'
        when d.Shift is not null then 'D'
        when d.Shift is not null then 'N'
        else '-'
        end as NorD
```

Comment: Just one thing, If I need to concatenate two shift columns , how to do that? (If an employee works both shifts then should be shown like 'D/N' ) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you dont need no temporary tables, just CTE. And also, you can use CASE to achieve `D/N` result:

```
 WITH vDAY as ( SELECT Atten_ID, EID, PID, DATEPART(DD,in_time) AS [Day], shift
   FROM Attendance
  WHERE (shift = 'D')
 ),
 vNIGHT as (
 SELECT Atten_ID, EID, PID, DATEPART(DD,in_time) AS [Day], shift
   FROM Attendance
  WHERE (shift = 'N')
 )
 SELECT COALESCE(d.EID,n.EID),
    COALESCE(d.PID,n.PID),
    COALESCE(d.Day,n.Day),
    CASE 
      WHEN d.Shift='D' and n.Shift='N' 
        then 'D/N'
      WHEN d.Shift IS NOT NULL then d.Shift
      ELSE COALESCE( d.Shift, '-' ) END
       AS DShift,
    CASE WHEN d.Shift='D' and n.Shift='N'
       then 'D/N' else COALESCE( n.Shift, '-' ) end
       AS NShift 
 FROM vDay d
    FULL JOIN vNight n ON 
       d.EID = n.EID AND d.PID = n.PID AND d.Day = n.Day
```

Comment: Thanks but there is a problem here as its giving null values if its not D/N. I'm trying to get this work.

Comment: You can post some ouput here so I can correct the query. Or you can extend my `case` statement in the way to achieve necessary result.

Comment: Finally values in the shift column should be like 'D', 'N', Or 'D/N'. But this query result is 'D/N','N'. No 'D' is shown instead it shows '-'. Yes we have to look into CASE

Comment: Try modified query, looks like some upper/lower case issue. `NOT NULL` is a more common condition, should work for Days